# Non-homogeneous wave equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

We have the following problem: 
$$v_{tt}=c^2v_{xx}+f(x,t), \ \ 0<x<\ell , \  t>0 \\ v(x,0)=\phi (x) , \ \ 0\leq x\leq \ell \\ v_t(x,0)=\psi (x) , \ \ 0\leq x\leq \ell \\ v_x(0,t)=v_x(\ell , t)=0 , \ \ t\geq 0$$ The general solution is of the form $$v(x,t)=u(x,t)+w(x,t)$$ where $u(x,t)$ is the solution of teh homogeneous differential equation $u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$.

So, we have to solve the following two problems:

The first one is: 
$$u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}, \ \ 0<x<\ell , \  t>0 \\ u(x,0)=\phi (x)-w(x,0) , \ \ 0\leq x\leq \ell \\ u_t(x,0)=\psi (x)-w_t(x,0) , \ \ 0\leq x\leq \ell \\ u_x(0,t)=u_x(\ell , t)=0 , \ \ t\geq 0$$ 
and the second problem is: 
$$w_{tt}=c^2w_{xx}+f(x,t), \ \ 0<x<\ell , \  t>0 \\ w(x,0)=0 , \ \ 0\leq x\leq \ell \\ w_t(x,0)=0, \ \ 0\leq x\leq \ell \\ w_x(0,t)=w_x(\ell , t)=0 , \ \ t\geq 0$$

Right? Or do we have to do something else?

Is everything is correct so far, the solution of the first problem can we found by d'Alembert's formula, or not?

How can we solve the second problem?

Answer (score 3):

d'Alembert's formula is for free space, so you won't have much luck with it. Even if you are able to find a solution, the B.C.s will not match up and you'll need another function to subtract off the boundary values. Overall, this results in a worse problem than before.

Here's a method that will work:

Note that the B.C.s are homogeneous. This suggests decomposing the solution into

$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{\lambda} T_\lambda(t) X_\lambda(x) $$

where $X\lambda(x)$ are eigenfunctions of the homogeneous problem

$$ X'' + \lambda^2X = 0 $$
$$ X'(0) = X'(\ell) = 0 $$

Solving this, you'll find
$$ X_n(x) = \cos(\lambda_nx) $$
$$ \lambda_n = \frac{n\pi}{\ell}, \quad n =0,1,2,\dots $$

This decomposition works because the $x$ eigenfunctions form a complete solution space in $[0,\ell]$. Plugging this in yields

$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n(t)\cos(\lambda_n x) $$

with the equation

$$ u_{tt} - c^2u_{xx} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \big[{T_n}''(t) + c^2{\lambda_n}^2T_n(t)\big]\cos(\lambda_nx) = f(x,t) $$

and initial values

\begin{align}
u(x,0) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n(0)\cos(\lambda_nx) = \phi(x) \\
u_t(x,0) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty {T_n}'(0)\cos(\lambda_nx) = \psi(x)
\end{align}

If you decompose these functions into their respective Fourier series, i.e.

\begin{align}
f(x,t) &= f_0(t) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(t) \cos(\lambda_n x) \\
\phi(x) &= \phi_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi_n \cos(\lambda_n x) \\
\psi(x) &= \psi_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \psi_n \cos(\lambda_n x)
\end{align}

Then we have the following family of ODEs that you can solve

$$ {T_n}'' + c^2{\lambda_n}^2 T_n = f_n(t) $$
$$ T_n(0) = \phi_n, \ {T_n}'(0) = \psi_n $$

**Edit:** The general solution is

\begin{align} 
T_n(t) &= \phi_n\cos\big(c\lambda_n t\big) + \frac{\psi_n}{c\lambda_n}\sin\big(c\lambda_n t\big) \\
&\quad - \frac{\cos\big(c\lambda_n t\big)}{c\lambda_n}\int_0^t \sin\big(c\lambda_n\tau\big)f_n(\tau)d\tau \\
&\quad + \frac{\sin\big(c\lambda_n t\big)}{c\lambda_n}\int_0^t \cos\big(c\lambda_n\tau\big)f_n(\tau)d\tau 
\end{align}

Comment: Is the solution of the last problem of the form $$T_n(t)=c_1\cos (c\lambda_n t)+c_2\sin (c\lambda_n t)$$ ? Then from $T_n(0)=\phi_n$ we have $c_1=\phi_n$. The derivative of $T_n$ is  $$T_n'(t)=-c_1c\lambda_n\sin (c\lambda_n t)+c_2c\lambda_n\cos (c\lambda_n t)$$ From $T_n'(0)=\psi_n$ we get $c_2c\lambda=\psi_n$. Therefore we get the solutions $$T_n(t)=\phi_n\cos (c\lambda_n t)+\frac{\psi_n}{c\lambda_n}\sin (c\lambda_n t)$$ Is this correct?

Comment: No. The solution you've written down is a solution to the homogeneous problem (where $f(t)=0$). The non-homogeneous problem can be solved using variation of parameters.

Comment: Ah ok. Can we solve that problem using that method without knowing the form of $f_n(t)$ ? Can we write the general solution of that problem?

Comment: Yes, the general solution has an integral form. See [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters)

Comment: To solve such DEs we have to use always the variation of parameters? Or are there also methods that we could use?

Comment: I haven't really understood how the general formula of variation of parameters is in the case of second order DEs.

Comment: Do we have to find the solution of the homogeneous problem and calulate their wronskian determinant?

Comment: I suggest you go back and read up on solving ODEs. Variation of parameters is a very well-known method and will work for most general functions if you don't know anything about $f(x,t)$. If the non-homogeneous function has a "nice" form, say $e^t$, $\sin t$ or any polynomial, you can use the method of Undetermined coefficients.

Comment: Ah ok! I have also an other question. At the Fourier series of $f(x,t), \phi (x), \psi (x)$ why do we use just $\cos $ and not also $\sin $ ?

Comment: The boundary conditions on $x$ determine the form of the eigenfunctions. The equation $X" + \lambda^2X = 0$ is derived from performing separation of variables on the homogeneous equation.